# How to prove that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q} \backsim \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My thoughts are -

Clearly I need to define a function $f:Z \times Q \rightarrow N$ such that the function is injective and $g:N \rightarrow Z \times Q$ is also injective, by Cantor.

Then, since $N \subset Z$ we can define $g(n) = (n, \frac{1}{2}), \forall n \in N$ which is trivially injective and then send any $n \notin N $ elsewhere.

My problem is, how do I define $f$ so that it is injective...

Answer (score 2):

Let $i_1: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ and $i_2: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ and $i: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ be bijections.

Then $n \mapsto (i_1([i(n)]_1,i_2([i(n)]_2)$ is a suitable bijection.

**Note**: The inverse function is
$(q,z) \mapsto i^{-1}(i_1^{-1}(q), i_2^{-1}(z))$. It follows that
the map is a bijection.

Comment: Very beautiful... Is there a way to define an injective function the way I have expressed it? Or is it easier to prove by bijection? Or is that in itself a dumb question.

Comment: Sure: the function that copper.hat gave is an injection.

Comment: Well, you can do it in many ways. This is a lazy way.

Comment: Any chance you are willing to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @sgerbhctim: What do you want me to elaborate?

Comment: How this function is defined both ways.. Is my above piece correct? And how does this define a bijective function. My question is, how did you intuitively come up with this? Can you prove that this function is injective and surjective?

Comment: The real work is establishing the bijection $i$ (product of natural numbers is also countable), the rest is window dressing. Instead of trying to unravel the formula, just think of $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ as alternative views of $\mathbb{N}$ and $i_1,i_2$ map back and forth between these views. The properties of $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Z}$  other than countability are irrelevant.

Comment: Hopefully my last comment answers your first two questions. I added an explicit inverse to  the answer. (Your answer shows half of what is required to apply Schröder Bernstein.)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Trying to absorb it.

Comment: @sgerbhctim: Focus on the $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ part, that is the real issue here.

Answer (score 0):

To prove an infinite set bijects with $\mathbb{N}$, you just need to order its elements so each element has finitely many predecessors, thereby arranging them all into an infinite list. If you know how to do this with $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, you'll be able to understand widely available proofs that $\mathbb{N}$ also bijects with $\mathbb{Q}$. Such proofs exploit the representation of rational numbers as ordered pairs of integers. Finally, if $f,\,g$ are bijections from $A,\,B$ to $\mathbb{N}$ while $h$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, $(a,\,b)\mapsto h(f(a),\,f(b))$ bijects $A\times B$ with $\mathbb{N}$; take $A=\mathbb{Z},\,B=\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

More generally than the other answers: Let $X, Y$ be two infinite sets. Then, $|X \times Y| = \max\{|X|, |Y|\}$.

Comment: I do forget how many extra axioms you need to assume for this, but I'm 75% sure it's true in just ZF.

Comment: No, it is not. Anyway, this is not very useful for the question at hand,  since you have now "reduced" the problem to something harder.